# data modeling in cassandra for CDR data

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to design a data model in cassandra for CDR (call detail records) data such that we could store and keep adding call details in same row of a same mobile number or a set of columns are added dynamically for each call by the same mobile number. Also it can support queries like, 
  which mobile no. called maximum times between two given date or given time(e.g., between 9AM   to 7PM)?

Your suggestions are are highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to designing Cassandra data models, the first thing you need to do is list all of the queries that need to be satisfied. Its also important to consider the amount of incoming CDR data (so that you can shard the data appropriately) and how frequently each query is likely to be run (so that the high frequency queries are matched against fast read performance).

Due to the non-relational nature of Cassandra, and the limited querying capabilities of CQL (compared to a traditional RDS), the database design is largely determined by the queries you need to run. Based on your examples, you will likely need multiple column families to satisfy those kinds of queries.

As a starting point, in terms of storing the raw CDRs, you could have a single 'wide row' column family where the row key is the mobile number and the column name is the timestamp of when the call was made. Then, for each CDR that comes in, you simply add a new column to the row matching that mobile number.

```
CDR_column_family
    mobile_number <- row key
        timestamp:null <- column name:column value
```

What you need to watch out for here is how wide the rows might become. If your dealing with the odd call every day then this might suffice, but if its more like hundreds of calls every day, you might want to shard the data so as not to degrade performance. So, your row key could become a mobile number/month composite (e.g. '07870 831137:201304'), and you will have a row per mobile number per month.

This CF will satisfy queries like "how many calls were made to 07870 831137 between 9AM and 7PM" but it wont tell you "which number was called the most between 9AM and 7PM", without querying every single row in the CF (which, in a distributed database, isnt going to be particularly efficient).

For a query like "which number was called the most between 9AM and 7PM", I would consider a second CF which would list all of the calls that were made in chronological order.

```
CallIndex_column_family
    month <- row key
        timestamp:mobile_number <- column name:column value
```

So every time you write to the CDR CF, you would also add a new column to the CallIndex CF, listing the time of the call and the number dialed. You can then query the CallIndex CF for all columns between two date/time ranges and parse the results to get the number which was called the most.

Comment: Thanks for your detail description, it helps me a lot to proceed in correct way..

Comment: i am not sure about this functionality, that is whether we can add set of column in a row repeatedly at different time? please give your opinion.

Comment: but in CDR_column_family, if we are considering mob. no. as a row key then number of rows would be very high (like in India there are around 960 million subscriber, so no. of row would be 960 million). so, it might cause low performance.

Comment: I believe adding columns to a row is a fairly inexpensive operation. Also, bear in mind that Cassandra will auto-sort columns for you, so using a timestamp (timeuuid) as the column name means cassandra can quickly find a range of columns between two dates.

Regarding having a billion rows in the CDR CF, you would only use this table to query for a specific mobile number, so cassandra only has to fetch at max a few rows to satisfy the query - meaning quick performance. If you were trying to run a query which required cassandra to scan all rows then yes, it would perform poorly.